# How to save csv datetime string into Django model field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to store DateTimeField data from csv to my model field but I am getting error

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Applications.submitted_at received a
>   naive datetime (2020-01-30 11:08:20.429620) while time zone support is
>   active.   RuntimeWarning)

my **models.py**

```
 submitted_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
 form_fill_up_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True),
```

how can I resolve this issue?

here is my function to convert csv string data into datetimefield

```
def date_check(data):#
    if data is None:
        print("Date Field is empty")
        return
    try:
        try:
            date_format1 = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
            date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, date_format1)
            return date_obj
        except ValueError:
            print('Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD')
            date_format2 = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, date_format2)
            return date_obj
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
```

Comment: That is by the way not an error, but a *warning*.

Comment: Django has a excellent docu about this topic -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/timezones/

Answer (score 1):

What you see is *not* an error, but a *warning*. It says that it is odd that you are running the server timezone-aware, and then you still pass a `datetime` object without a timezone. You can add a timezone, like UTC to your `datetime` object:

```
from pytz import utc

def date_check(data):#
    if data is None:
        print("Date Field is empty")
        return
    try:
        try:
            date_format1 = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
            date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, date_format1)
            return utc.localize(date_obj)
        except ValueError:
            print('Incorrect data format, should be YYYY-MM-DD')
            date_format2 = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
            date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(data, date_format2)
            return utc.localize(date_obj)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return
```